# How to force user to submit jobs in a certain directory in slurm

Tags: slurm

I am trying to setup SLURM such that SLURM accepts the job submitted in a certain directory and rejects the job otherwise.

To activate prolog script, I have set slurm.conf up as follows:

```
PrologSlurmctld=/etc/slurm-llnl/prolog/dircheck-prolog
```

dircheck-prolog script is in /etc/slurm-llnl/prolog which reads

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $PWD = /home/slek/Desktop/scratch/* ]];
then
    exit 0
fi
exit 1
```

However, job are still submitted regardless of the submitted location.
Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hey, like you I set PrologSlurmctld and like you the script does not get executed.
I'm wondering whether you manged to make this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation states that the `PrologSlurmctld` parameter must be a

> Fully qualified pathname of a program for the slurmctld daemon to execute before granting a new job allocation

From your sentence

> dircheck-prolog script is in /etc/slurm-llnl/prolog

I assume that your `/etc/slurm-llnl/prolog` is actually a directory. Slurm should probably complain somewhere in the logs.

So try replacing `PrologSlurmctld=/etc/slurm-llnl/prolog`  with `PrologSlurmctld=/etc/slurm-llnl/dircheck-prolog`

BUT

This script will start at **job allocation**, i.e. after it is submitted, when resources have been reserved/found for it. If you want to filter the submissions themselves, you will need to use a *job submit plugin* (see the `JobSubmitPlugins` options in `slurm.conf`).

> These are intended to be site-specific plugins which can be used to set default job parameters and/or logging events.

Sample scripts in Lua are shipped with Slurm under `contribs/lua/job_submit*.lua`. There, you can implement any logic with respect to job submission, offer error messages, re-route jobs, assign QOS automatically, etc.

Comment: According to your comment, I have corrected slurm.conf but still job is submitted

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try your solution.